# C++ Struct with pointers : constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, dll, struct, destructor

I am having a problem with a simulation program that calls a DLL to perform an optimization task. After having studied this issue for a certain time, I think my problem lies in the destructor I use to free memory after the DLL has returned the desired information. The simulation program was developed on Borland C++ Builder v6 and the DLL was developed on MS Visual C++ 2005.

For the simulation program (P) and the DLL to exchange data, I created two structures `InputCPLEX` and `OutputCPLEX` and a function `optimize` that takes two arguments: one object of type `InputCPLEX` and one object of type `OutputCPLEX`. Both structures are declared in a header file `structures.h` which belongs to the P project and the DLL project.

Both `InputCPLEX` and `OutputCPLEX` structures have `int` and `int*` members, so basically the  file `structures.h` looks like :

```
//structures.h
struct InputCPLEX{
  public:
  int i;
  int* inputData;
}
struct OutputCPLEX{
  public:
  int j;
  int* outputData;
}
```

The idea is that along the simulation process (the execution of P), I periodically call the DLL to solve an optimization problem, so `inputData` is the array corresponding to the variables in my optimization problem and `outputData` is the array of optimal values for my variables. I know that it would have been easier to use the STL containers, such as `vector<int>`, however - correct me if I am wrong - it seems it is difficult to exchange STL objects between two different compilers.

Here is how things look in my main file (in P):

```
//main.h
InputCPLEX* input;
OutputCPLEX* output;
int* var;
int* sol;

//main.cpp    
[...] //lots of code
input = new InputCPLEX;
output = new OutputCPLEX;
int n = X; //where X is an integer 
var = new int[n]; 
[...] //some code to fill var
input->i = n; 
input->inputData = var; 
optimize(input,output); //calls the DLL
int m = output->j; 
sol = new int[n];
sol = output->outputData;
[...] //some code to use the optimized data
delete[] var;
delete[] sol;
delete input;
delete output;
[...] //lots of code
```

For more than one year I have been using this code without any constructor or destructor in the file `structures.h`, so no initialization of the structures members was performed. As you may have guessed, I am no expert in C++, in fact it's quite the opposite. I also want to underline that I did not code most of the simulation program, just some functions, this program was developed for more than 10 years by several developers, and the result is quite messy.

However, everything was working just fine until recently. I decided to provide more information to the DLL (for optimization purposes), and consequently the simulation program has been crashing systematically when running large simulations (involving large data sets). The extra information are pointers in both structures, my guess is that the program was leaking memory, so I tried to code a constructor and a destructor so that the memory allocated to the structures `input` and `output` could be properly managed. I tried the following code which I found searching up the internet :

```
//structures.h
struct InputCPLEX{
  public:
  int i;
  int* inputData;
  int* inputData2; // extra info
  int* inputData3; // extra info
  InputCPLEX(): i(0), inputData(0), inputData2(0), inputData3(0) {}
  ~InputCPLEX(){ 
    if (inputData) delete inputData;
    if (inputData2) delete inputData2;
    if (inputData3) delete inputData3;
  }
}
struct OutputCPLEX{
  public:
  int j;
  int* outputData;
  int* outputData2;
  int* outputData3;
  OutputCPLEX(): j(0), outputData(0), outputData2(0), outputData3(0) {}
  ~OutputCPLEX(){ 
    if (outputData) delete outputData;
    if (outputData2) delete outputData2;
    if (outputData3) delete outputData3;
  }
}
```

But it does not seems to work: the program crashes even faster, after only a short amount of time. Can someone help me identify the issues in my code? I know that there may be other factors affecting the execution of my program, but if I remove both constructors and destructors in `structures.h` file, then the simulation program is still able to execute small simulations, involving small data sets.

Thank you very much for your assistance,
David.

Comment: `delete` on a null pointer as no effect. The `if`s in the destructor are unnecessary. And you should follow the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B-faq]+rule+of+three).

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by 
>`delete` on a null pointer has no effect
Do you mean that when I delete the objects `input` and `output` it automatically deletes their members, so I don't need to state that in the destructor ?

Comment: It means that you don't have to check whether a pointer is NULL or not before deleting it.

Comment: Ok I understand, I'll remove the `if`s. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use consistent way of new - delete. If something was acquired by `new[]` you should delete it by `delete[]`, if by `new` -> delete by `delete`. In your code you create `input` and `output` by `new` but delete via `delete[]`.

BTW, you do not have to check a pointer for zero before deletion. `delete` handles zero pointers with no problems.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, there was a mistake in the code I posted : I did use `delete` and not `delete[]` to delete the objects `input` and `output`. I corrected my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems in your code:

1) Memory leak/double deletion:

```
sol = new int[n];
sol = output->outputData;
```

Here you override `sol` pointer right after initialization and data allocated by `new int[n]` is leaked. Also you double delete pointer in `sol` - second time in destructor of `output`. The same problem with `var` - you delete it twice, by explicit `delete[]` and in destructor of `input`.

Double deletion problem is raised after you have added destructors with `delete`, looks like before it was not a problem.

Also as @Riga mentioned you use `new[]` to allocate array, but `delete` instead of `delete[]` in destructors. This is not correct and this is Undefined Behavior. Despite this doesn't look like crash cause. In real world most compilers don't make difference implementing `delete` and `delete[]` for built-in and POD types. Serious problems can arise only when you `delete` array of objects with non-trivial destructors.

2) Where `output->outputData` is allocated? If in DLL it is another problem, as you usually cannot safely deallocate memory in your main program if it was allocated in DLL implemented with another compiler. The reason is different `new/delete` implementation and different heaps used by runtimes of main program and DLL.

You always shall allocate/deallocate memory on same side. Or use some common lower-level API - e.g. `VirtualAlloc()/VirtualFree()` or `HeapAlloc()/HeapFree()` with same heap handle.

Comment: About your fisrt point: I will remove the first data allocation `sol = new int[n];`. However, I am not sure I understand the double deletion: `var` and `sol` pointers are not members of the structures `InputCPLEX` or `OutputCPLEX`. Therefore, they are not deleted twice but only once by explicit `delete[]`. I dont see why the destructor of `input` would delete `var`. As far as what @Riga and you suggest, I have corrected the deletion of `input` and `output` but should I remove the `delete` instructions in the destructors? (From what you tell me I think I should).

Comment: About your second point, your guess is right: `output->outputData` is allocated in the DLL. But I can allocate it before using the optimize function by filling `outputData` with dummy values, should I do that?

Comment: @David Yes, they aren't members of the structures, but they hold **the same pointer value** as you assigned. Assignment of pointers copies the value of pointer (the address it points to), not the structure it points to. You could have a lot of pointers pointing to same structure in memory, but **only one** can be used to delete it. This is named **ownership**.

Comment: @David about second point - you should allocate and delete the memory you passed to DLL in main program, that's correct. What do you mean by dummy values, zeros to fill allocated array pointed by `outputData`?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thank you for the insight on pointers. If I understand correctly I could remove the destructors (or leave them empty) and just delete explicitly the pointers `sol` and `var`?

Comment: @David Yes, this should work. But this is definitely not good design & style. Usually the class controls its memory structures allocating them in constructor and deallocating in destructor.

Comment: Ok I will review my code and I'll post a feedback after having performed some tests (it takes a while for the large scale simulations to run). Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks odd:

```
int m = output->j; 
sol = new int[n];
sol = output->outputData;
```

as far as I understood it you return the size in m but allocate with n
then you overwrite the array by setting the pointer (sol) to outputData
I think you meant something like:

```
int m = output->j; 
sol = new int[m];
memcpy(sol,output->outputData,sizeof(int)*m);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the `m` integer was just for the sake of the example. I mean `sol = new int[n];`, i.e. I want to allocate the an array of size `n`.